# Integration by parts: integrating both sides

Tags: calculus, integration

Integration by parts is defined by the formula $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$. Let's says $\int udv=\int lnxdx$. When determining what $v$ equals, I learned that this requires integrating both sides of $dv=1dx$. 
$$\int dv=\int 1dx$$
$$v+C=x+K$$
Are the constants $C$ and $K$ going to be equal to each other or different? $v+C=x+K$ doesn't even seem to carry any meaning because one antiderivative is in terms of $v$ while the other is in terms of $x$. My biggest confusion is integrating both sides of an equation with respect to different variables. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The constants you get can be put together on one of the sides. $v=x+C$ (sums of arbitrary constants are just arbitrary constants)

Comment: It would be helpful to give some more context, e.g., how this relates to integration by parts.

Comment: Also, what does $dv=1dx$ mean to you?

Comment: @BallBoy is that better?

Comment: @user532874 It's still not clear from your presentation where $x$ comes from and what the formula $dv=1dx$ means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$v=x+(K-C)$$
Both K and C are real arbitarry constants so $K-C$ also must be a real constant.

Secondly, The equation you got just a relationship between $x$ and $v$

For example, $v=x+10$

differentiate both sides you get $\frac{dv}{dx}=1$

$$dv=1 dx$$

Comment: Why is $v$ assumed to be a function of $x$? That's the only way you are allowed to take the derivative operator with respect to $x$ of $v$, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}[v]$.

Comment: Can you share the function you are integrating ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll be more comfortable thinking about it this way:

We have an integral $\int f dx$ (in your example $f(x)=\ln x$) and want to make a substitution $f(x)=u(x)\frac{dv(x)}{dx}$ so the integral becomes $\int u\frac{dv}{dx}dx$. We solve for $v(x)$ in your example by starting with $$\frac{dv}{dx}=1$$ and then integrating both sides with respect to $dx$ giving 
$$\int\frac{dv}{dx}dx=\int1dx$$

The left side is $v(x)+C$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and the right side is $x+K$. Then, as in Harshit Gupta's answer, we combine the constants and one side and get $v(x)=x+(K-C)$.

Answer (score 0):

> My biggest confusion is integrating both sides of an equation with respect to different variables. It doesn't make sense to me.

Actually what we have here $$\mathrm dv =\mathrm dx$$ is called a differential equation. It relates the differential of two quantities. In particular it says that their differentials are equal. So we have simply integrated these differentials along their respective domains in such a way that these domains correspond to each other as described by the relationship between the quantities, and we find the result that the quantities $v$ and $x$ differ only by a constant.